How does $[J^2, J_+] = 0$, but $ | l, m \rangle $ is not an eigenstate of $J_+$?
I am currently working on the angular momentum part (chapter 3) of Sakurai's QM 2nd. From eq. 3.159 and eq. 3.154, the book says $[J^2, J_+] = 0$ and $[J^2, J_z] = 0$, but I don't understand why $| l, m \rangle $ is not an eigenstate of $J_+$ (eq. 3.164)? Doesn't the commutation relation tell us $J^2$ and $J_+$ share the same eigenstates, so the eigenstates of $J^2$ are also the eigenstates of $J_+$?
Mathematically, if we apply two states $ |  l, m \rangle $ and $ |  l', m' \rangle $,
$$  \langle l', m'|[J^2, J_+]| l, m \rangle = \hbar ^2(l'(l'+1) - l(l+1))\langle l', m'|J_+ | l, m \rangle = 0$$
Doesn't this mean $ |  l, m \rangle $ is an eigenstate of $J_{+}$?

edition, chapter, page, equations numbers?

2nd edition, chapter 3, p182, eq(3.164).

Edit the question accordingly...

The states you are examining are eigenstates of $J_z$. Does this commute with $J_+$?

Your confusion is explained very well in the duplicate.

Thank you, this answers my question.

It all comes down to the theorem that states that when two (finite-dimensional) linear functions commute and are both diagonalizable then they are simultaneously diagonalizable. The operators $J^2$ and $J_\pm$ do indeed commute, as you correctly stated, but they do not share a basis of eigenvectors because the $J_\pm$ do not have such a basis, as they are not diagonalizable in the first place.

Thank you, I didn't know that $J_+$ cannot be diagonalized.
